# How do you get the graph plugin for Squirrel SQL?

Tags: installation

I installed Squirrel SQL and the website claims the Graph plugin is part of the install.  It is not available nor is it in the jar.  How do I get the graph plugin?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Installation documentation](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=plugins) the correct version of each available plugin is always provided in the SQuirreL SQL Client install jar.

> Graph Plugin by Gerd Wagner
>
> Installer Category: Standard
>
> This plugin allows you to create and print charts of database tables and their foreign key relations. If you use it together with the SQL Scripts plugin you are able to script tables from within the charts.

You can download it from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.squirrel-sql.plugins/graph/3.2.1

Comment: It wasn't in the install.  That was my problem.  I used 7zip to look inside.  Just not there.  Thanks for the link.